# Room + RxJava 2 How to check for a record in a table in which a column is equal to a specific value

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java2, android-room

I have a user table. I need to check if a user with a specific name exists. I am doing this with this code

UserDao

```
  @Query("SELECT * FROM User WHERE userName = :userName")
  fun getUserByUserName(userName :String) : Observable<User>
```

Using

```
  repository.getUserByUserName(input)
                .observeOn(mainThread())
                .subscribe(user -> {

                });
```

After I subscribe to this Observable, but this only works for the case when such a user exists, but if the user is not in the database, subscribe does not work. How can I handle the situation when the user is in the database and when he is not?

Comment: you may use `Maybe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Single(or Maybe as Beloo suggested) instead of Observable.

You can try something like this :

```
repository.getUserByUserName(input)
                .observeOn(mainThread())
                .subscribe(user -> {

                }, 
                throwable -> {
                // catch your exception here.                   
                }));
```